# US Taxes Free Fillable Forms Error

Tags: united-states, taxes, free-file-fillable-forms

I'm getting an obscure error using FreeFillableForms.  The error does not appear to be on the [standard table of X000-005 errors](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf).

> Issue      : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation. cvc-complex-type.2.4.b.  The content of element 'WagesNotShownSch' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.irs.gov/efile":WagesNotShownAmt}' is expected.
>
> The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
>   Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf)/efile:ReturnData[1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf)/efile:WagesNotShownSchedule[1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf)/efile:WagesNotShownSch[1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf)/efile:WagesLiteralCd[1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-utl/Fixing-Your-XML-Error.pdf)

How can I fix this?